# Restrict/remove delete functionality

Tags: data-recovery, delete

Is there any way to remove delete functionality from the easily accessible UI components, especially the photo gallery? It's way too easy to access and delete things you shouldn't, e.g. friends trying to delete bad pictures of themselves and accidentally deleting other photos, not to mention issues like deletion by clueless law enforcement officers who don't know the law. The ideal behavior would be to leave the "delete" function in place but move all deleted content to a hidden location rather than actually deleting it.